# Facebook API 3.0 - error with NewPermissionRequest

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to learn the Facebook API for Android on eclipse and as a starting point trying to get the Scrumptious app running.

In the "SelectionFragment.java" src file, I'm getting the following error

"The method NewPermissionsRequest(SelectionFragment, List) is undefined for the type "

at

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
if (session != null) {
        PERMISSIONS = session.getPermissions();
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = Session.NewPermissionsRequest (this, PERMISSIONS)
                // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
                // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
                .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                .setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
```

I've cleaned both Facebook SDK and Scruptious and gone through the Session.java src in facebook SDK but can't seem to identify the error.

Appreciate any inputs please. thanks

Comment: Does your SelectionFragment extend Fragment, and is it using android.support.v4.app.Fragment? The SDK uses the support library, so if you're importing android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment, it could give you that error.

Comment: You have to new your `Session.NewPermissionsRequest` object.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and added `new` before `Session.NewPermissionsRequest...` and the error went away. Hope this helps.

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
```